# Does boiling time changes if kept a fixed volume water in a pan with wider base and a pan comparatively less wider base?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Does boiling time changes  if I kept a Given amount of volume of any liquid say water , 1. In a wider base pan 2. A comparatively less wider base cooking pan kept on a kitchen burner  ??

(Both pan are made of same material)
Many answer I look mention :-

" wider base allow more heat  contact with pan and doesn't allow any of heat flame escape from side like in case of less wider base"

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> " wider base allow more heat contact with pan and doesn't allow any of
> heat flame escape from side like in case of less wider base"
>
> Is that right?

Yes, that's right.

We can see it also from [Newton's Law of cooling/heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling):

$$\dot{Q}=hA\left(T_{pan}-T_{flame}\right)$$

A wider base, all other things being equal, increases $A$ and thus $|\dot{Q}|$.

Comment: Gert, as a person who has had experience with this OP, I just want you to be aware that this is at least the third account this OP has created, including "Anshika Sing" and the latest (incognito) account "user315474", that involve at least 12 questions about similar topics of vaporization or evaporation. You may want to review the questions and answers given under the latest account (user 31574) before you answer any follow up questions the OP may have, so that you know where he/she is coming from.

Comment: @BobD Ah. Good to know, Bob. Thanks!

Comment: @bob D , sorry ...I have already told I used that OP that for chemistry , I am a well reputed student and of class 10 from India . So I don't have any alternate option to get answers that's why I use physics exchange, please sir...it's my humble request don't make people think it as a fraud account, I am trying my best to learn things. Here , there is no one to solve conceptual doubts so I used this place , please

Comment: @Gert , thanks a lot sir...I was confused. Thank u and please don't think it as  a fraud account , I am student of class 10th

Comment: @Gert , thanks a lot sir...I was confused. Thank u and please don't think it as  a fraud account , I am student of class 10th

Comment: @Suresh Chandra Pal I never said it was a fraud account. Sorry if it sounded that way. But why is it that all your questions originally under the Anshika Sing account are now under a new user31574 account and that they can no longer be viewed? Contributors should be able to see what has already been asked and answered on essentially the same topic before they invest their time trying to help you.

Comment: The main comment here is the correct one!